issue trying to inject text programaticaly with js on deviantart: continu button remain disabled
I'm trying to automate the insertion of text into a rich text editor on deviantart (likely powered by React). The issue I'm facing is that while I can successfully inject the text into the editor, the "Continue" button, which should allow me to proceed, remains disabled. The button only activates when I manually type a character in the editor, which seems to suggest that the application is expecting a specific user interaction to validate the input.
I use the automa web chrome extension and i try to inject the text with the javascript custum block
Basic Text Insertion:
Initially, I tried using textContent and innerHTML to insert the text directly into the editor. The text appears in the correct place, but the "Continue" button stays disabled.
Simulating Input Events:
I then tried to simulate various events such as input, change, focus, blur, and keydown/keyup to mimic user interaction. Despite these efforts, the button remains disabled unless a manual keypress is made.
Simulating a Complete User Interaction:
We attempted to simulate a more complete interaction by combining the insertion of text with simulated mouse clicks and keypresses. This approach also included dispatching additional events like paste and using intervals to re-check the state of the "Continue" button. Unfortunately, the button is still not activated.
The "Continue" button activates only when I manually type a character in the editor after the script has run, indicating that the application is likely detecting or expecting a specific type of user event that we haven't successfully simulated.
Here is the actual code:
var textElement = document.querySelector('#placeholder-journalBody');

if (textElement) {
    // Focus on the editor to simulate user interaction
    textElement.focus();

    // Clear the existing content
    textElement.textContent = '';

    // Insert the new text
    var newText = "salut";
    textElement.textContent = newText;

    // Simulate a click inside the editor
    var clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window });
    textElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

    // Simulate a keypress to activate the "Continue" button
    var keyDownEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key: 'a', code: 'KeyA', charCode: 97 });
    textElement.dispatchEvent(keyDownEvent);
    
    var inputEvent = new InputEvent('input', { bubbles: true, inputType: 'insertText', data: 'a' });
    textElement.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);

    var keyUpEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true, key: 'a', code: 'KeyA', charCode: 97 });
    textElement.dispatchEvent(keyUpEvent);

    // Simulate a 'blur' event after the modification
    var blurEvent = new Event('blur', { bubbles: true });
    textElement.dispatchEvent(blurEvent);

    // Simulate a 'change' event to signal the end of the modification
    var changeEvent = new Event('change', { bubbles: true });
    textElement.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);

    // Re-check the state of the validation button
    var continueButton = document.querySelector('.reset-button._1Vx2f._1tjfK._3Lsf7');
    if (continueButton && !continueButton.disabled) {
        continueButton.click();
    } else {
        console.log("Continue button is still disabled");
    }
} else {
    console.log("Text element not found");
}

